# how to determine which files has been changed from those in rcs

Tags: c++, c, repository, cvs, rcs

I am working with a c++ codebase using rcs repository (agh, old I know),  during major code changes, I modify a lot of files, which I sometimes lose track of. So I would like to have a small script which will list the files that are different (those that I changed) from files  in the repository. It is sort of unrealistic to do rcsdiff on each file. Assume that all files are in the same directory. Is there a small script or alias that will list all the files I have modified?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow.
RCS is designed for source control of a single file.
It is rarely used directly. CVS is a system that is layered ontop of RCS to extend the functionality to a bunch of files (ie a project).

You could do it in the shell with:

```
tcsh
foreach a ( `ls *.cpp` )
  echo ${a}
  echo "=============================================================="
  rcsdiff ${a}
  echo "=============================================================="
  echo
  echo
  echo
end
```

If you had been using cvs I would suggest using tags:
Tag before you start modifying and then tag at regular check points.

```
cvs tag <startChangeTag>
```

Then you can compare any of the files against the the tagged version.

Comment: I like this solution, however, i don't want to printout files that haven't been modified.

Comment: by adding the -q flag you supress any extra noise

Comment: I did use RCS in anger (_way_ back!), before any of the newfangled CVS thingies showed up (and after, when the local nature of RCS was invaluable). Don't disparage the tools of our forebears.

Comment: @vonbrand: Me too. I see no disparagement. But now its time to use git.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I left RCS behind. But I still keep the original RCS around, for old time's sake